# Devise working local but not working on heroku

Tags: heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a app http://agile2go.herokuapp.com/ using devise + cancan.

Running the app locally works fine but when deployed on Heroku the `sign_up` page displays an error message.  However, the sign_in page works fine!

I know the problem is when calling resource in simple_form_for, when I took the resource out it worked:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

It works on `sign_in` page!

Here is my routes.rb

```
authenticated :user do 
  root :to => "home#index"
end
root :to => "home#index"     
devise_for :users, :path => "auth"
```

On the Navbar when click on links:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>//works
<li><%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>//does not work
```

Finally the Heroku logs:

```
2013-04-07T21:55:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/sign_up" for 177.143.148.73 at    2013-04-07 21:55:15 +0000
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<User:0x00000004317050>):
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= f.error_notification %>
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= f.input :password, :placeholder => 'Password', :required => true, input_html: { class: 'text_field input-xlarge' } %>
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Confirmation', :required => true, input_html: { class: 'text_field input-xlarge' } %>
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= f.input :email, :placeholder => 'Email', :required => true, input_html: { class: 'text_field input-xlarge' } %>
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= f.input :name, :placeholder => 'Name', :autofocus => true, input_html: { class: 'text_field input-xlarge' } %>
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__4395295283282032383_35150600'
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__4395295283282032383_35150600'
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= display_base_errors resource %>  
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-07T21:55:16+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/auth/sign_up host=agile2go.herokuapp.com fwd="177.143.148.73" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=228ms status=500 bytes=643
```

I don't know why its saying undefined method `name` for `#<User:0x00000004317050>`

Comment: have you ran all your migrations on Heroku? Does `$ heroku run rake db:migrate:status --app app_name` report any pending migrations?

Comment: Fixed! the migration I did, did not created the column name on my model user.rb...TKS Anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue - `raking` fixed this for me. Try this in your console:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```